# ESD protections when working with laptops

Tags: laptop-repair

If I was standing on carpet working on a laptop on a wood table, what would be the best method  to protect the laptop from ESD damage?
Should I get an ESD mat and lay the laptop out on the mat? Is that enough?
Or would an ESD wristband work? And if so, what would I attach it to, since you normally attach it to an unpainted metal part of the case. That's a little hard to find on a laptop.

Or does anyone have any better recommendations?

Comment: *"ESD wristband ... normally attach it to an unpainted metal part of the case."* - That is misinformation.  Such a connection serves no purpose, unless the case was properly grounded (to earth) (e.g. plugged into an AC outlet w/ a 3-prong plug).  Two-prong plugs do not guarantee proper grounding.  The proper connection for an ESD wristband is earth ground, such as the screw on a electrical outlet wall cover.

Answer (score 0):

After 20+ years, i never seen any damage caused by ESD to laptops, to towers, to components touched with unprotected hands, etc. Nothing, never.
I've heard a lot about it over the Internet, but never seens the smallest evidence, from myself or from someone I know.
And I'm sure you never seen anything too, nor the people you know.
So my (very personnal) advice is: just don't care.

Comment: I used to think that, but recently I was working on a laptop, and I'm pretty sure I damaged it cause of ESD. So.. was thinking about investing a little into some protection.

Comment: @Josh - it's a cheap insurance that you can use again and again